# Replacing vector in LPP

Tags: linear-programming

If we have the following,
$$
\text{max: } z = c^Tv
$$
$$
\text{s.t } Av = u
$$
$$
v \geq 0
$$
If this is unbounded, then can I state that for any vector $u'$ other than $u$ it will either be unbounded or infeasible

Comment: The Lagrange dual of your problem consists in maximizing the linear function $-u^\intercal\, x$ subject to $A^\intercal x + c \ge 0$. Now, if $u$ varies, the admissible set is fixed and only the objective functions changes. It could help for finding a counterargument.